# WYSIWYG Rich Text Editor Textarea show wrong

Tags: php, mysqli, wysiwyg, str-replace

```
// Filter Function -------------------------------------------------------------------
function filterFunction ($var) { 
    $var = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($var));
    $var = str_replace("/", "\\\\", $var);
    $var = preg_replace("~/~", "\\\\", $var);

    return $var; 
}
```

I have a problem with my CMS if i try to edit some text, is giving me some `</h2>` and `</p>` at the end if i try to edit a `h2`.

I think the problem is here, but how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example you've provided, the problem appears to be these two lines:

```
$var = str_replace("/", "\\\\", $var);
$var = preg_replace("~/~", "\\\\", $var);
```

The first line says to replace all forward slashes with double back slashes. So `</h2>` becomes `<\h2>`. The second line does the same thing, but since you're doing it twice the `</h2>` becomes `<\\h2>`.

Removing these lines will resolve your issue. But if you're doing this intentionally, perhaps you could clarify why, or what exactly you're trying to achieve. Maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: Indeed i fixed, removed those line from the content variable and now works, thank you